# Implement parameters in function

Tags: jquery, parameters, increment

Hello i created this function :

```
function addNewStaticTab(int)
{

    if (int === undefined) int = "int";

    $.addDynaTab({
        tabID : 'addstatictab',
        type : 'html',
        html : '<table class="fontStreet" width="100%"> <tr> <td align="left" class="td-label">Intitulé*</td> <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td> <td align="left" width="150"><input type="text" class="input-middle" required></td> <td> <figure onclick="makeCaptionAppear(\''+ int +'\');" style="position:relative; padding:0px; margin:0px;" ><img src="img/inter.png" id="buttonCriteresLeft"><figcaption class="figcaptionRoster2" id='+ int +' onMouseOut="makeCaptionDisappear(\''+ int +'\');">Aide:<br> Exemples d\'intitulés :<br>Projet, développement commercial, développement international, En création, prestataire, apporteur d\'affaires, recherche d\'emploi/opportunités, etc.</figcaption></figure> </td> </tr> </table><br>',
        params : {},
        tabTitle : 'NOUVELLE ACTIVITÉ'
    });
}
```

I want to each time i call this function, the parameter **int** is incremented

For example:

int1
int2
etc..

It's maybe simple but i don't manage to find what i want..

**EDIT :**

Here's the button to call the fonction : `<a class="new"><button name="addNewStaticTab" id="addNewStaticTab" value="Add New Static Tab" onClick="javascript:addNewStaticTab();" style="font-size:16px; background:none; border:0;"><b>+</b> </button></a>`

and the function call : `$(document).ready(function() {
        //add static tabs
        $("#addstatictab").dynatabs({
            tabBodyID : 'addstatictabbody',
            showCloseBtn : true,
            confirmDelete : true
        }); 
    });`

Comment: um, int is passed in.... So how is it being called?

Comment: looking in the wrong place ... where is `int` defined to pass into the function?

Comment: Do you wnat int to be 'int1', 'int2', ...? or just a number as 1, 2, ... ?

Comment: I want int to be "int1, etc.."

Answer (score 0):

I think i have to modify this line :

```
<a class="new"><button name="addNewStaticTab" id="addNewStaticTab" value="Add New Static Tab" onClick="javascript:addNewStaticTab();" style="font-size:16px; background:none; border:0;"><b>+</b> </button></a>
```